# C Program pointer being realloc'd was not allocated

Tags: c, pointers, realloc

I tried to create two sub array of one array by some conditions and use realloc to increase the pointer space. 
However, this code:showed pointer being realloc'd was not allocated.
There are totally 5 items and this failed on 4th items. I am really confused why it can succeed for first 3 items.

```
void sortHand(Hand *hand, Suit trump) {
  int length = NUM_CARDS_IN_HAND - 1;
  Card *cards = getAllCardsFromHand(hand, length);
  Card *trumpCards = (Card*)malloc(sizeof(Card));
  Card *otherCards = (Card*)malloc(sizeof(Card));
  int trumpCount = 1, otherCount = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i <= length ; i++) {
    Card curtCard = cards[i];
    if (curtCard.suit == trump){
      trumpCount = addCardsBySuit(trumpCards, curtCard, trumpCount);
      printf("trumpCount %d\n", trumpCount);
      continue;
    }
      otherCount = addCardsBySuit(otherCards, curtCard, otherCount);
      printf("otherCount%d\n", otherCount);
  }
  if (trumpCards == NULL) {
    printf("Trump is zero. Other is %d.", (otherCount + 1));
    addAllCardsTohand(otherCards, hand, otherCount);
    return;
  }
  if (otherCards == NULL){
    printf("Other is zero. Trump is %d.", (trumpCount + 1));
    addAllCardsTohand(trumpCards, hand, trumpCount);
    return;
  }
  printf("Trump is %d. Other is %d.", (trumpCount + 1), (otherCount + 1));
  addAllCardsTohand(trumpCards, hand, trumpCount);
  addAllCardsTohand(otherCards, hand, otherCount);
}
```

I think problem is in this function.

```
int addCardsBySuit(Card *trumpCards, Card card, int trumpCount) {
  printf("addCardsBySuit\n");
  Card *moreCards = (Card*)realloc(trumpCards, trumpCount * sizeof(Card));
  trumpCards = moreCards;
  trumpCards[trumpCount] = card;
  trumpCount++;
  return trumpCount;
}
```

This is my test code and output.

```
void test_sort_hand() {
  start_test("sort_hand");
  Hand *hand = createHand();
  Card card1 = {NINE, HEARTS, -1};
  addCardToHand(&card1, hand);
  Card card2 = {JACK, HEARTS, -1};
  addCardToHand(&card2, hand);
  Card card3 = {ACE, HEARTS, -1};
  addCardToHand(&card3, hand);;
  Card card4 = {QUEEN, HEARTS, -1};
  addCardToHand(&card4, hand);;
  Card card5 = {TEN, SPADES, -1};
  addCardToHand(&card5, hand);
  printHand(hand);
  sortHand(hand, HEARTS);
  printHand(hand);
  end_test();
}

0: Ten_Spades
1: Queen_Hearts
2: Ace_Hearts
3: Jack_Hearts
4: Nine_Hearts
addCardsBySuit
otherCount2
addCardsBySuit
trumpCount 2
addCardsBySuit
trumpCount 3
addCardsBySuit
test(5155,0x11820d5c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fd811402b50: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
test(5155,0x11820d5c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: In general, if you allocate an object to size N, and then attempt to reference element N, you are overstepping the boundary.  That is, if an array has size N, then referencing `array[N]` is an error.  If a pointer is allocated to have size `trumpCount * sizeof(Card)`, you can access it as an array by indexing `0` thru `trumpCount -1`

Comment: Your problem is the result of the _realloc_ it not visible by the caller of _addCardsBySuit_ and the next _realloc_ on the next loop turns are invalid, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
int addCardsBySuit(Card *trumpCards, Card card, int trumpCount) {
  printf("addCardsBySuit\n");
  Card *moreCards = (Card*)realloc(trumpCards, trumpCount * sizeof(Card));
  trumpCards = moreCards;
  trumpCards[trumpCount] = card;
  trumpCount++;
  return trumpCount;
}
```

out of *addCardsBySuit* the value of *trumpCards* is unchanged, so the next time you will call *addCardsBySuit* and you try to *realloc* it again you will do on the old value not valid anymore rather than the previous result of *realloc*

You can change with

```
int addCardsBySuit(Card **trumpCards, Card card, int trumpCount) {
  printf("addCardsBySuit\n");
  Card *moreCards = (Card*)realloc(*trumpCards, trumpCount * sizeof(Card));
  *trumpCards = moreCards;
  (*trumpCards)[trumpCount] = card;
  trumpCount++;
  return trumpCount;
}
```

of course changing the call to give the address where the pointer is :

```
void sortHand(Hand *hand, Suit trump) {
  int length = NUM_CARDS_IN_HAND - 1;
  Card *cards = getAllCardsFromHand(hand, length);
  Card *trumpCards = (Card*)malloc(sizeof(Card));
  Card *otherCards = (Card*)malloc(sizeof(Card));
  int trumpCount = 1, otherCount = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i <= length ; i++) {
    Card curtCard = cards[i];
    if (curtCard.suit == trump){
      trumpCount = addCardsBySuit(&trumpCards, curtCard, trumpCount);
      printf("trumpCount %d\n", trumpCount);
      continue;
    }
      otherCount = addCardsBySuit(&otherCards, curtCard, otherCount);
      printf("otherCount%d\n", otherCount);
  }
...
```

Comment: It worked! The lesson should be that if I want to change a pointer which is outside the function, I need to use a pointer of the pointer to do it. Am I right?

Comment: @AlexFan whatever the type of a variable, if you want to change the value at the caller level you can give a pointer to it (so a double pointer if case the type of the var is a pointer) the parameter being an input-output parameter rather than just an input parameter, an other solution is to return the new value to allow the caller to memorize the new value, but here you already return a value

Comment: @AlexFan so you can also change to have `addCardsBySuit(Card **trumpCards, Card card, int *trumpCount)` where _trumpCount_ is also an input-output parameter and the caller does not have to do `trumpCount = addCardsBySuit(&trumpCards, curtCard, trumpCount);` but `addCardsBySuit(&trumpCards, curtCard, &trumpCount);`, and of course dereferencing _trumpCount_ in _addCardsBySuit_ like it was necessary for  _trumpCards_